# Remove space between the words from 5th column

Tags: awk

I have data

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1 A2))            2
IA2    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    ((!A1 A2) A3)        3
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1 A2) B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1 A2) A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)                1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2) A3) B1))  4
```

How can I remove space between the words from field 5 i.e fun column
, so that when I do `column -t` they are perfectly aligned.

I tried to used

```
sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+//5'
```

But this removes only the 1st space between words in 5th column.

Comment: Is the data otherwise tab-separated? Then simply replace all spaces with nothing.

Comment: You accepted an answer that assumes you always have 2 blanks between columns but I don't see anything in your question to indicate that there couldn't be 2 blanks in a column (specifically `fun`) or just 1 blank between columns on a given row. I suspect that might be a solution that works for the posted example but won't work in future for the real data. You;d have to tell us more about what separates the fields in your data to be sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a custom `FS` with 2 or more whitespaces:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '{gsub(/ +/, "", $5)} 1' file | column -t
```

```
cell  input        out  type  fun                level
AI20  A1,A2        Z    comb  ((A1A2))           2
IA2   A1,A2,A3     Z    comb  ((!A1A2)A3)        3
XOR   A1,A2,B1     Z    comb  (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD   A1,A2,A3     Z    comb  (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV   I1           ZN   comb  (!I1)              1
BUF   A1,A2,A3,B1  Z    comb  (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to remove spaces from `(` to till `)` then you could try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/\(.*\)/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/ +/,"",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  val=""
}
'  Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/\(.*\)/){                     ##using match function to match from ( to till ) here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)         ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex value.
  gsub(/ +/,"",val)                     ##Globally substituting spaces with NULL in val here.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  ##Printing sub string from 1 to till just before RSTART val and rest of the line then.
  val=""                                ##Nullifying val here.
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl,

```
$ perl -pe ' s/\(.*\)/($t=$&)=~tr! !!d;$t/gme ' neha2.txt
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))            2
IA2    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    ((!A1A2)A3)        3
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)                1
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
$
```